# Can I include a data CD or DVD with a book when self-publishing on Amazon?

Tags: self-publishing, amazon

I would like to self-publish a school workbook on Amazon. I won't be selling as an eBook, as it is intended that users write in the workbook. There will be a teacher's edition that needs to come with a CD or DVD that holds some additional digital files that accompany the book, e.g. PowerPoints for the teacher to use along with the book. Amazon sells media through "Amazon Media on Demand", but I found that won't allow for data disks, only audio CDs or video DVDs. Does Amazon allow for a disk to be packaged and shipped sold together with the book? Or do they have a service allowing me to sell the data disk on Amazon separately?

Comment: I just took a quick look at the help after signing into my KDP account. The only references that I see to CD or DVD are the places they tell you that your digital book shouldn't include any references to something that is only available as part of the physical book, such as CDs. I wouldn't take this as a definitive answer, though.